# Simple BigInt for sum and difference

Tags: c++, object-oriented, integer

I am working on a school project where we need to add and subtract large integers in C++. I will also be adding multiplication and division in the next couple days. So far it appears like everything is running fine. I haven't had any noticeable errors but I am trying to improve my skills so any kind of feedback is appreciated.

*(I fixed the bug involving the carry digit in both the subtraction and addition methods in my class. Before when a user added two numbers and there was a carry over from one column to the next it would drop down instead of being added correctly e.g. 1982 + 35 returned 11017 instead of 2017. There was a similar issue with subtraction, both were pointed out by [@Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39848/edward).)*

[GitHub](https://github.com/dmikey098/BigInteger)

**source.cpp**

```
#include "BigInt.h"
#include <vector>
string getNumberInput();
int showMenu();

int main() {
    BigInt firstNum;
    BigInt secondNum;
    BigInt answer;
    bool done = false;
    std::vector<BigInt> vIntegers;


    while (!done) {
        switch (showMenu()) {
        case 1:
            answer = BigInt("0");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                vIntegers.push_back(BigInt(getNumberInput()));
            }

            for (BigInt integer : vIntegers) {
                answer = answer + integer;
            }

            std::cout << "The sum is " << answer.getStringInt() << "." << std::endl;
            vIntegers.clear();
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                vIntegers.push_back(BigInt(getNumberInput()));
            }
            answer = vIntegers[0] - vIntegers[1];

            std::cout << "The difference is " << answer.getStringInt() << "." << std::endl;
            vIntegers.clear();
            break;
        case 4:
            if (vIntegers[0] > vIntegers[1]) {
                std::cout << "True";
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            done = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
            }
        }

    return 0;
}

string getNumberInput() {
    string tempStr;

    std::cout << "Enter number: ";
    std::cin >> tempStr;
    return tempStr;
}

int showMenu() {
    int option;
    std::cout << "\n1. Get sum" <<
                 "\n2. Get difference" <<
                 "\n9. Exit" <<
                 "\nMake a selection: ";
    std::cin >> option;
    return option;
}
```

**BigInt.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using std::deque;
using std::string;

class BigInt
{
public:
    BigInt();
    ~BigInt();

    BigInt(string s);
    bool getNegative();
    friend BigInt operator+(BigInt b1, BigInt b2);
    friend BigInt operator-(BigInt b1, BigInt b2);
    friend bool operator> (BigInt b1, BigInt b2);
    friend bool operator< (BigInt b1, BigInt b2);
    static void addIntegers(deque<int> d1, deque<int> d2, BigInt &returnValue);
    static void subIntegers(deque<int> d1, deque<int> d2, BigInt &returnValue);
    void printInt();
    const deque<int> getDigits();
    void addToFront(int);
    void setNegative(bool);
    int getSize();
    string getStringInt();
    int getInteger();

private:
    deque<int> vDigits;
    bool negative;
};
```

**BigInt.cpp**

```
#include "BigInt.h"

BigInt::BigInt()
{
    negative = false;
}


BigInt::~BigInt()
{
}

BigInt::BigInt(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    string neg = s.substr(0,1);
    if (neg == "-") {
        negative = true;
        i = 1;
    }
    else {
        negative = false;
    }
    for (i; i < s.size(); i++) {
        vDigits.push_back(s[i] - '0');
    }
}

bool BigInt::getNegative()
{
    return negative;
}

void BigInt::printInt() {
    for (int i = 0; i < vDigits.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vDigits[i];
    }
}

const deque<int> BigInt::getDigits()
{
    return vDigits;
}

void BigInt::addToFront(int number)
{
    vDigits.push_front(number);
}

void BigInt::setNegative(bool val)
{
    negative = val;
}

int BigInt::getSize()
{
    return vDigits.size();
}

string BigInt::getStringInt()
{
    bool leadingZero = true;
    string str;
    if (negative) { str = "-"; };
    for (int i : vDigits) {
        if (i == 0 && leadingZero) {
            str = str;
        }
        else {
            str = str + std::to_string(i);
            leadingZero = false; //when a non-zero number is found flag is set to false so zeros will be including thereafter
        }

    }
    return str;
}

int BigInt::getInteger()
{
    return 0;
}

BigInt operator+(BigInt b1, BigInt b2)
{
    BigInt returnValue;
    deque<int> firstNum;
    deque<int> secondNum;

    if (b1.getSize() >= b2.getSize()) {
        firstNum = b1.getDigits();
        secondNum = b2.getDigits();
    } else {
        firstNum = b2.getDigits();
        secondNum = b1.getDigits();
    }

    BigInt::addIntegers(firstNum, secondNum, returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}

BigInt operator-(BigInt b1, BigInt b2)
{
    BigInt returnValue;
    bool isNegative = false;
    deque<int> firstNum;
    deque<int> secondNum;

    if (b1 > b2) {
        firstNum = b1.getDigits();
        secondNum = b2.getDigits();
    }
    else {
        firstNum = b2.getDigits();
        secondNum = b1.getDigits();
        returnValue.setNegative(true);
    }

    if (b1.getNegative() && !b2.getNegative()) {
        BigInt::addIntegers(firstNum, secondNum, returnValue);
        returnValue.setNegative(true);
    }
    else {
        BigInt::subIntegers(firstNum, secondNum, returnValue);
    }
    return returnValue;
}

bool operator>(BigInt b1, BigInt b2)
{
    bool larger = false;
    if (b2.getNegative()) {
        if (!b1.getNegative()) {
            larger = true;
        }
    }

    if (b1.getSize() > b2.getSize()) {
        larger = true;
    }
    else if (b1.getSize() == b2.getSize()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < b1.getSize(); i++) {
            if (b1.getDigits()[i] >= b2.getDigits()[i]) {
                larger = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return larger;
}

bool operator<(BigInt b1, BigInt b2)
{
    bool larger = false;
    if (b1.getNegative()) {
        if (!b2.getNegative()) {
            larger = true;
        }
    }

    if (b1.getSize() < b2.getSize()) {
        larger = true;
    }
    else if (b1.getSize() == b2.getSize()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < b1.getSize(); i++) {
            if (b2.getDigits()[i] >= b1.getDigits()[i]) {
                larger = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return larger;
}

void BigInt::addIntegers(deque<int> firstNum, deque<int> secondNum, BigInt &returnValue) {
    int tempInt = 0, storeInt = 0, carryInt = 0;
    int sizeDiff = firstNum.size() - secondNum.size();

    for (int i = firstNum.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (i - sizeDiff < 0) {
            tempInt = (firstNum[i] + carryInt);
            storeInt = tempInt % 10;
            carryInt = tempInt / 10 % 10;
            returnValue.addToFront(storeInt);
            //carryInt = 0;
        }
        else {
            tempInt = (firstNum[i] + secondNum[i - sizeDiff]) + carryInt;
            storeInt = tempInt % 10;
            carryInt = tempInt / 10 % 10;

            returnValue.addToFront(storeInt);
        }
    }
    if (carryInt != 0) { returnValue.addToFront(carryInt); };
}



void BigInt::subIntegers(deque<int> firstNum, deque<int> secondNum, BigInt &returnValue) {
    int storeInt = 0;
    int sizeDiff = firstNum.size() - secondNum.size();

    for (int i = firstNum.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (i - sizeDiff < 0) {
            storeInt = firstNum[i] % 10;

        }
        else {
            if (firstNum[i] < secondNum[i - sizeDiff]) {
                firstNum[i] += 10;
                if (firstNum[i - 1] == 0) {
                    firstNum[i - 1] = 9;
                    firstNum[i - 2]--;
                }
                else {
                    firstNum[i - 1]--;
                }
            }
            storeInt = (firstNum[i] - secondNum[i - sizeDiff]);
        }
        returnValue.addToFront(storeInt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Fix the bugs

The current program is improved, but bugs remain.  In particular, negative numbers don't seem to be handled correctly.  This leads to the next suggestion.

### Write and run automated tests

Writing and running automated tests is one very good way to both find bugs in your code and to assure that any changes you might make later don't introduce new bugs.  Here's a simple framework that you could use for this code:

```
bool testAdd(const BigInt &a, const BigInt &b, const BigInt &c) {
    auto res = a+b;
    bool ok = res == c;
    std::cout << (ok ? "OK:  " : "Err: ") << a << " + " << b << " = " << c;
    if (!ok) {
        std::cout << ", but got " << res;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return ok;
}

bool testSub(const BigInt &a, const BigInt &b, const BigInt &c) {
    auto res = a-b;
    bool ok = res == c;
    std::cout << (ok ? "OK:  " : "Err: ") << a << " - " << b << " = " << c;
    if (!ok) {
        std::cout << ", but got " << res;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return ok;
}

int main() {
    struct {
        BigInt a, b, c;
    } test[]{
        { {"35"}, {"1982"}, {"2017"} },
    };
    for (const auto t : test) {
        testAdd(t.a, t.b, t.c);
        testAdd(-t.a, -t.b, -t.c);
        testAdd(t.b, t.a, t.c);
        testAdd(-t.b, -t.a, -t.c);
        testAdd(t.c, -t.a, t.b);
        testAdd(t.c, -t.b, t.a);

        testSub(t.c, t.b, t.a);
        testSub(t.c, t.a, t.b);
        testSub(-t.c, -t.b, -t.a);
        testSub(-t.c, -t.a, -t.b);
        testSub(t.b, t.c, -t.a);
        testSub(t.b, -t.a, t.c);
    }
}
```

Running this test would require implementation of the next three suggestions.

### Define unary `-` operator

One simple way to provide this useful operator would be this:

```
BigInt BigInt::operator-() const
{
    BigInt ret{*this};
    ret.negative = !negative;
    return ret;
}
```

Note that because this returns a copy of the original, and doesn't modify the original, it's declared `const`.

### Define the `==` operator

It's generally useful to implement a `==` operator for numeric classes like `BigInt`, as well as a `!=` operator.

### Use `friend operator<<` as custom print function

It would be convenient to be able to write things like this:

```
BigInt firstNum("1982");
std::cout << firstNum << '\n';
```

This can be done like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const BigInt &big) {
    if (big.isNegative()) {
        out << '-';
    }
    for (const auto dig: big.vDigits) {
        out << dig;
    }
    return out;
}
```

### Don't use `#pragma once`

While it is widely supported, it's not in the standard.  If you want to write programs that are guaranteed to be portable, the use of the standard "include guards" is recommended instead.  That is, each header would look like this:

```
#ifndef BIGINT_H
#define BIGINT_H
// file contents here
#endif // BIGINT_H
```

### Separate interface from implementation

The header file (`.h` file) should only include the interface, leaving details about the implementation to the corresponding `.cpp` file.  In this case, for example the following `#include`s should be moved from the interface to the implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

### Only `#include` needed headers

The `<sstream>` header is included but not used and should be omitted from `BigInt.h`.

### Prefer modern initializers for constructors

Instead of writing this:

```
BigInt::BigInt()
{
    negative = false;
}
```

You can instead write this:

```
BigInt::BigInt() : 
    vDigits{}, 
    negative{false}
{}
```

if you're using a C++11 compliant compiler.  If you're not using such a compiler, you're really doing yourself a disservice by learning an antique version of C++.  For that reason, many of the further suggestions will use C++11 constructs and techniques.

### Let the compiler generate defaults

The compiler will automatically generate destructor if you let it.  If you want to be explicit about that, instead of writing an empty destructor, write this:

```
~BigInt() = default;
```

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor quality code, and you don't want to write poor quality code. In this code, `isNegative` within `operator-` is unused.  Your compiler is smart enough to tell you about this if you ask it nicely.

### Use better names

Instead of `getSize()` and `getNegative()`, I'd suggest `size()` and `isNegative()`.

### Use `const` where practical

A number of the member functions, such as `getSize` do not alter the underlying `BigInt` and should therefore be declared `const` as in:

```
int getSize() const;
```

### Simplify the constructor

The current constructor looks like this:

```
BigInt::BigInt(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    string neg = s.substr(0,1);
    if (neg == "-") {
        negative = true;
        i = 1;
    }
    else {
        negative = false;
    }
    for (i; i < s.size(); i++) {
        vDigits.push_back(s[i] - '0');
    }
}
```

This has a few problems.  First, it makes a copy of the passed `std::string` which really isn't necessary.  It could instead take a `const std::string &s` instead.  Second, there is no need to create `neg` -- all that's needed is to look at the first character.  Third, it doesn't handle a malformed input string at all.  Fourth, the first clause of the `for` string is strange and has no effect -- it would be better to simply omit it.  Fifth, `s.size()` is unsigned, but `i` is declared a signed.  It would be better to make `i` either `unsigned` or `std::size_t`.

### Define `+` using `+=`

A very common and useful idiom with numerical classes such as this is to first define a `+=` operator and then define the freestanding `+` operator using that.  So, for example, once a correct `operator+=` is implemented, we can very easily define the `+` operator:

```
BigInt operator+(BigInt b1, const BigInt &b2) {
    return b1 += b2;
}
```

Note that the only the second operand is passed as a reference, so the first one creates a copy of the passed `BigInt` which we can then use with the `operator+=` already defined.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Your advice is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping to get. I'll keep at it and implement your suggestions!

Comment: @Edward: Could you write something more about construction ```struct {
        BigInt a, b, c;
    } test[]{```? I haven't seen such use of lambda. And why do you use ```for (const auto t : test)``` when test.size is 1 in this case?

Comment: @trivelt: It's not a lambda.  It's an array of an unnamed `struct`.  I only showed one entry to illustrate the framework, but in real code there would be more, which is why the `for` loop is written as it is.